Google Sheets - Condition formatting
I'm trying to make a sheet where multiple teams are listed in six columns split between the two top teams, two middle teams and two bottom teams. I have the formula for getting the cell with the higher value already as
=INDEX(B$5:C$5, 1, MATCH(MAX(B5:C5), B5:C5, 0))

that works fine, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I am trying to get the sheet to output either a color or word based on what cell has the higher value.
so if for instance cell B5 has 7 and C5 has 9 then it would show say red for C and blue for B. Is this even something Sheets supports?
the sheet I am using for this is
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18dRKXiHz7UP6vHXM_ybOiPFviuropN5q-XUAROD1IOg/edit?usp=sharing
Thank you for any support or information.

try in I2:
=BYROW(B2:C, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(1/(1/MAX(x)))))


update:
=BYROW(B2:INDEX(C:C, MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:C<>""))), 
 LAMBDA(x, INDEX(FILTER(B1:C1, MAX(x)=x),,1)))



 =(B2=MAX($B2:$C2))*(B2<>"")


or:


so this shows similar but much better formatting but still does not do the output part the way Im attempting for. If the Column was colored with their value would we be able to pull the cell color with value? just throwing thoughts out.

@mengle updated with conditional formatting

you are absolutely awesome! and I see you set a color condition formatting so I assume if Top-E it colors it red?

@mengle sure: https://i.sstatic.net/6H9S5nJB.png
